# Reading the attributes and elements in an XML using Openxml in SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have the XML shown below. I want to read the XML attributes and the elements using `openxml`, please could you help me out?

```
<Report>
     <Datapoints>
             <Datapoint>10</Datapoint>
             <Datapoint>11</Datapoint>
     </Datapoints>
<Filters>                 
        <Filter Id="5" FilterTypeId="4">            
            <Option2>21</Option2>
            <Option2>22</Option2>             
            <Option2>23</Option2>
        </Filter>        
        <Filter Id="6" FilterTypeId="4">            
            <Option2>21</Option2>
            <Option2>22</Option2>             
            <Option2>23</Option2>
        </Filter>   
    </Filters>           
</Report>
```

I want to read the attributes in tag `Filter` (`Id` and `FilterTypeId`) along with element `option2`.

Answer (score 2):

Why `OPENXML` ?? Seems overly klunky and hard to use - use the XPath/XQuery capabilities in SQL Server !

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Report>
     <Datapoints>
             <Datapoint>10</Datapoint>
             <Datapoint>11</Datapoint>
     </Datapoints>
<Filters>                 
        <Filter Id="5" FilterTypeId="4">            
            <Option2>21</Option2>
            <Option2>22</Option2>             
            <Option2>23</Option2>
        </Filter>        
        <Filter Id="6" FilterTypeId="4">            
            <Option2>21</Option2>
            <Option2>22</Option2>             
            <Option2>23</Option2>
        </Filter>   
    </Filters>           
</Report>'
SELECT
    Filter.value('(@Id)[1]', 'int') AS 'FilterID',
    Filter.value('(@FilterTypeId)[1]', 'int') AS 'FilterTypeID',
    Opt2.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Option2'
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/Report/Filters/Filter') AS Rep(Filter)
CROSS APPLY 
    Filter.nodes('Option2') AS Rep2(Opt2)
```

This should give you an output something like:

```
FilterID  FilterTypeID  Option2
   5            4          21
   5            4          22
   5            4          23
   6            4          21
   6            4          22
   6            4          23
```

Basically, the first use of `.nodes()` (with the alias of `Rep(Filter)`) will create a "pseudo-table" of all `<Filter>` XML tags (one row for each XML tag) and the first two items in the `SELECT` are grabbing attributes out of each of the `<Filter>` XML tags.

Then, you need to have a second enumeration, of all `<Option2>` elements inside each filter - that's what the second `.nodes()` call is doing - based on the filter XML tag from the first pseudo-table. This then just outputs the XML tag's content as its value.

Comment: XPath/XQuery is better approach to deal with XML.